# 1054 - Unknown column 'XXX' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

The SQL statement below used to work a few years ago, now it doesn't and I get this error message:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Promotion_Card_details.Card_id' in 'on clause'

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Promotion_Card_details.Card_id, 
       Promotion_Merchant_details.Merchant_id, 
       Promotion_details.Promotion_id, 
       Issuer_details.IssuerName, 
       Card_details.CCType, 
       PaymentType_details.PaymentTypeName, 
       Merchant_details.MerchantName, 
       PromotionText, 
       PromotionEndDate 
FROM Promotion_details 
INNER JOIN Card_details ON (Card_details.Card_id=Promotion_Card_details.Card_id) 
INNER JOIN Issuer_details ON (Issuer_details.Issuer_id=Card_details.Issuer_id) 
INNER JOIN PaymentType_details ON (PaymentType_details.PaymentType_id=Card_details.PaymentType_id) 
INNER JOIN Merchant_details ON (Merchant_details.Merchant_id=Promotion_Merchant_details.Merchant_id) 
INNER JOIN Promotion_Merchant_details ON (Promotion_Merchant_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_details.Promotion_id) 
INNER JOIN Promotion_Card_details ON (Promotion_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_Card_details.Promotion_id) 
WHERE ((Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '13' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '14'  
            OR 
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '15' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '16' OR 
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '17' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '18' OR 
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '19' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '20' OR
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '21' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '22' OR 
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '23' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '24' OR 
      Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '25' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '361' 
      OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '364' OR Promotion_details.Promotion_id = '382') )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried parentheses around certain parts, but it still hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Could you post a DESC of your table?

Comment: Did someone rename or delete the field in the `Promotion_Card_details` table?

Comment: Also, it'd make the query a bit more readable to change your `WHERE` clause to use `IN` instead of a long list of `OR`'s.

Comment: Promotion_Card_details is a table with a primary key, and two foreign keys: promotion_id from the promotion_details table and card_id frmo the card_details table. Similarly, the Promotion_Merchant_details table has a primary key, and two foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Hi Alex K, my SQL statement is being generated by Perl dynamically, so although its all Promotion_details.Promotion_id in the example above, it can be mixed with Merchant_details.Merchant_id and other constraints in other examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`JOIN`s are left-associative, so a given `ON` clause can only refer to tables that have already been mentioned. So, reorder these:

```
FROM Promotion_details 
   INNER JOIN Card_details ON (Card_details.Card_id=Promotion_Card_details.Card_id) 
   INNER JOIN Issuer_details ON (Issuer_details.Issuer_id=Card_details.Issuer_id) 
   INNER JOIN PaymentType_details ON (PaymentType_details.PaymentType_id=Card_details.PaymentType_id) 
   INNER JOIN Merchant_details ON (Merchant_details.Merchant_id=Promotion_Merchant_details.Merchant_id) 
   INNER JOIN Promotion_Merchant_details ON (Promotion_Merchant_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_details.Promotion_id) 
   INNER JOIN Promotion_Card_details ON (Promotion_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_Card_details.Promotion_id)
```

into this order:

```
FROM Promotion_details 
   INNER JOIN Promotion_Card_details ON (Promotion_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_Card_details.Promotion_id)
   INNER JOIN Card_details ON (Card_details.Card_id=Promotion_Card_details.Card_id) 
   INNER JOIN Issuer_details ON (Issuer_details.Issuer_id=Card_details.Issuer_id) 
   INNER JOIN PaymentType_details ON (PaymentType_details.PaymentType_id=Card_details.PaymentType_id) 
   INNER JOIN Promotion_Merchant_details ON (Promotion_Merchant_details.Promotion_id=Promotion_details.Promotion_id) 
   INNER JOIN Merchant_details ON (Merchant_details.Merchant_id=Promotion_Merchant_details.Merchant_id)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it. It doesn't matter how I re-order all my INNER JOIN statements, the first INNER JOIN will always give the error #1054 - Unknown column 'XXX' in 'on clause'

Comment: @James: Ah, I hadn't noticed that there are other mis-ordered dependencies. But it's still the same problem. I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Yeh sorry I noticed a typo in my SQL statement above, and I think the one I put up there to replace, is correct now, which throws the #1054 - Unknown column 'Promotion_Card_details.Card_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic ruakh. It worked! I can't believe it was about re-ordering the INNER JOIN statements.

Comment: thanks for that: "a given ON clause can only refer to tables that have already been mentioned." my query looked perfectly fine but I did not know that!